# How to cut a string from a string

Tags: regex, string, bash, unix, cut

My script gets this string for example:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3.../importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file
```

let's say I don't know how long the string until the `/importance`.

I want a new variable that will keep only the `/importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file` from the full string.

I tried to use `sed 's/.*importance//'` but it's giving me the path without the `importance`....

Here is the command in my code:

```
find <main_path> -name file | sed 's/.*importance//
```

### I am not familiar with the regex, so I need your help please :)

Sorry my friends I have just wrong about my question,
I don't need the output `/importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file` but `/importance/lib1/lib2/lib3` with no /file in the output.

Can you help me?

Comment: Given the current solutions, just pipe: `... | sed 's#/file##'`

Comment: but the file name is not constant

Comment: I only know that the file is last in the string

Comment: See the update in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27841004/1983854 Also, you should read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `awk`:

```
$ echo "/dir1/dir2/dir3.../importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file" | awk -F"/importance/" '{print FS$2}'
importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file
```

Which is the same as:

```
$ awk -F"/importance/" '{print FS$2}' <<< "/dir1/dir2/dir3.../importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file"
importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file
```

That is, we set the field separator to `/importance/`, so that the first field is what comes before it and the 2nd one is what comes after. To print `/importance/` itself, we use `FS`!

All together, and to save it into a variable, use:

```
var=$(find <main_path> -name file | awk -F"/importance/" '{print FS$2}')
```

---

### Update

> I don't need the output `/importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file` but
>   `/importance/lib1/lib2/lib3` with no /file in the output.

Then you can use something like `dirname` to get the path without the name itself:

```
$ dirname $(awk -F"/importance/" '{print FS$2}' <<< "/dir1/dir2/dir3.../importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file")
/importance/lib1/lib2/lib3
```

Comment: I think I will go with your idea, it is more elegant

Answer (score 1):

Instead of substituting all until importance with nothing, replace with `/importance`:

```
~$ echo $var
/dir1/dir2/dir3.../importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file
~$ sed 's:.*importance:/importance:' <<< $var
/importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file
```

As noted by @lurker, if `importance` can be in some `dir`, you could add `/`s to be safe:

```
~$ sed 's:.*/importance/:/importance/:' <<< "/dir1/dirimportance/importancedir/..../importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file"
/importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file
```

Comment: And to be safer, I think I'd use `s:.*/importance/:/importance/:` just in case there's some other string like `fooimportancebar` that shouldn't be matched.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
echo '/dir1/dir2/dir3.../importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file' | sed -E 's#.*(/importance.*)#\1#'
```

Output:

```
/importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file
```

Comment: It is doenst recognize the -E, I tried with -e but it still didn't work, thanks anyway

Comment: If you prefer `-e`: escape `(` and `)` with a `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

### pure bash

```
kent$ a="/dir1/dir2/dir3.../importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file"

kent$ echo ${a/*\/importance/\/importance}   
/importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file
```

### external tool: grep

```
kent$ grep -o '/importance/.*' <<<$a    
/importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to use `sed 's/.*importance//'` but it's giving me the path without the `importance`....

You were very close. All you had to do was substitute back in `importance`:

```
sed 's/.*importance/importance/'
```

However, I would use Bash's built in [pattern expansion](http://man.cx/bash#heading14). It's much more efficient and faster.

The pattern expansion `${foo##pattern}` says to take the shell variable `${foo}` and remove the largest matching glob pattern from the left side of the shell variable:

```
file_name="/dir1/dir2/dir3.../importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file"
file_name=${file_name##*importance}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removeing the `/file` at the end as you ask:

```
echo '<path>' | sed -r 's#.*(/importance.*)/[^/]*#\1#'
```

- Input `/dir1/dir2/dir3.../importance/lib1/lib2/lib3/file`
- Returns: `/importance/lib1/lib2/lib3`

See this "[Match groups](http://regexone.com/lesson/11)" tutorial.